# JPA Annotations, lists opposed to separately included instances

Tags: java, jpa

It is pretty clear to me when using JPA with a collection of data, how to annotate a member which is of type List, ArrayList, Collections, etc.  (@OneToMany or @ManyToMany etc), but what if we have the following:

```
    @Entity    
    class page{

        Person creator;
        Person modifier;
        Person owner;
    }
```

In this case, I want to make the design decision to not have any sort of collection of person entities, but rather separately listed variables.  I am confusing myself as to how to correctly annotate these members.

Am I correct in assuming that I should annotate them as if they were a list even though they are listed separately, ie

@ManyToMany because "Many Pages include many Persons" and "Many Persons are involved in Many Pages" as opposed to @ManyToOne "Many Pages include One Creator instance of Person" (There is no Creator entity only person, and creator would only be the member variable of Page) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a ManyToOne relationship.

What this says is simple:

@ManyToOne

1. How many pages can a person create? Many.
2. How many persons can create a single page? One

@ManyToMany

1. How many pages can be modified by a single person? Many
2. How many persons can modify a single page? Many (But i would go for OneToMany here and have a list of Persons who modified the page. @ManyToMany would be a tricky a fair)

@ManyToOne

1. How pages can be owned by a single person?Many
2. How persons can own a single page? One (Well sometimes you can have more than one owner,
   but in your scenario, am guessing only one owner is desired)

So:

```
@Entity
public class Page{

 @ManyToOne
 private Person creator;
 @OneToMany
 private List<Person> modifiers;
 @ManyToOne
 private Person owner; //which i guess may be the same as owner.

}
```

Comment: this actually makes a great deal of sense when you really think about how the SQL tables should look like.  the table of page then would include the foreign key of a person in the column of creator and owner, and a connection to a joining table for modifiers.  Awesome.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You might be annotating it differently based on what is your desired design.

You can do it simply like this, clearly distinguishing the roles. This would be preferred solution if Page has to connect only to three people with three roles and this is not about to change.

```
@Entity    
class Page{
    @ManyToOne
    Person creator;
    @ManyToOne
    Person modifier;
    @ManyToOne
    Person owner;
}
```

However if you assume the number of roles may change in a system, you can design it differently. For instance:

```
@Entity    
class Page{
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name="PAGE_PERSON")
    Map<PersonType, Person> people;
}
```

And PersonType being and Enum:

```
enum PersonType {
    CREATOR, MODIFIER, OWNER
}
```

You gain additional flexibility. The next step in gaining flexibility would be to swap PersonType from being an Enum to being a full fledged Entity. But like I said it all depends on your preferred design. You know the system you are modelling the best.

Comment: Again, awesome idea.  I had thought of this and want to use this for another application I am working on.  In this instance, however, I was really looking for a design of having the possibile members listed separately and not exclusively for a Page(s) to Person(s) entity relationships